# Python переход к следующей функции пока работает предыдущая с циклом while

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Код выглядит так :

```
@application.route('/healing', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def healing():
    asyncio.run(healing())
    return redirect("/character")

async def healing():
    while current_user.hp_current < current_user.hp_max:
        current_user.hp_current += 1
        db.session.commit()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("хил функция запустилась")
```

Я думал, что ассинхронная функция будет работать на фоне, но нет.
Пока условие while не выполнится следующее действие не выполняется "return redirect("/character")"
Тоже самое, если бы я использовал обычную функцию, а не ассинхронную.
При этом, если я вручную перехожу на другие страницы, функция продолжает работать.

Мне нужно чтобы переходя на страницу "healing" - запускался бы процесс лечения на фоне и сразу перенаправляло куда мне надо.